# Why is the shape of my transformed data from CountVectorizer 2x2?

Tags: scikit-learn, preprocessing, reshape

I am currently working on a text classification problem using Python and scikit-learn. I am using CountVectorizer to convert my text data into numerical vectors. I have also applied a preprocessor to clean and process the data before feeding it into the vectorizer.

After vectorizing the training data using the code below, I noticed that the shape of the transformed data is 2x2:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(preprocessor=preprocessor)
X_train_vec = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
```

However, the shape of the original X_train data is (4134, 2). I expected the shape of X_train_vec to be something like (4134, n), where n is the number of unique words in the corpus.

Why is the shape of my transformed data 2x2 and how can I fix this issue?